# When we use 'to cause to be'?

Tags: verbs, american-english, british-english

> Please help me to understand when we should use it(**to cause to be**) in
>   English? Does it have any relation with **make**?

Please check the below link to understand my question completely.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/make_3

Answer (score 2):

As your link says, "to cause to be" is a definition of the word "make". As such, the phrase and the word can be fairly interchangeable when used that way.

"The jalapenos *caused* my salsa *to be* too spicy." "The jalapenos *made* my salsa too spicy."

"Chlorine *makes* my hair dry." "Chlorine *causes* my hair *to be* (or to become) dry."

I can't think of a circumstance where "to cause to be" would be preferable to "make", but it's correct as long as you're consistent with tenses. *Make* is simpler.